How do I pass command line parameters to a python prgram called from XMLHTTPRequest
I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to pass command line paramters to a python program called by javascript XMLHTTPRequest.  In my python program I have used each of sys.argv, getopt and argparse, all of which work when run from the command line but not when called from the Javascript script.  In my Javascript program I have tried:
xhr.open('GET', 'https://solarpredictor.co.uk/test.py?solcast&full&graph', true);
xhr.open('GET', 'https://solarpredictor.co.uk/test.py?s=solcast&f=full&g=graph', true);

and
xhr.open('GET', 'https://solarpredictor.co.uk/test.py?solcast', true);

none of which work.  In every case the parameters are not being found by the py program.
How can I get the python program to retrieve parameters when called within XMLHTTPRequest?
For what it is worth, this is my python program:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

solcast = False
full = False
graph = True

print("len = ",len(sys.argv))
for x in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    param = sys.argv[x]
    print(param)
    if param == 'solcast':
        solcast = not solcast
    elif param == 'full':
        full = not full
    elif param == 'graph':
        graph = not graph

print(solcast,full,graph)


How are you hosting the test.py script?

It's on my own server, solarpredictor.co.uk, and, in fact, in the same directory as the html file.

What software are you using on the server? Apache? Nginx?

Lighttpd.  The point I'd make is that the python program works fine when called through XMLHTTPRequest with no parameters - and also works fine when called with parameters.  It is just that it does not receive those parameters.

You don’t pass command line parameters. You aren’t running the script on the command line.
You have some way of interfacing your HTTP server with your Python code. Last time I looked at Python the way commonly regarded as best was WSGI but other approaches such as mod_python and CGI are available. (Your comments suggest you are using CGI).
The common Python libraries for those interfaces have functions for reading query strings from the request URL.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI


Thank you for that.  I need to read the link and then see how to apply it to my case

Thank you! I have now got it working using cgi & cgitb
